# stripping a query string with php (preg_replace)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

http://www.chuckecheese.com/rotator.php?cheese=4&id=1

I want to take out the id, leaving the cheese to stand alone.  I tried:

```
$qs = preg_replace("[^&id=*]" ,'',$_SERVER[QUERY_STRING]);
```

But that said I was using an improper modifier.  I want to remove "$id=" and whatever number comes after it.  Are regexp really as hard as they seem for me?

Comment: thanks, I just happened to read the other answer first so I gave him the green.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting an improper modifier because you need to surround your expression with an arbitrary delimeter. I tend to use `!` because I rarely want to look for that but `/`, `~` and others are common. So:

```
$qs = preg_replace('!&id=.*!', '', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

The other way to do this is using [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). For example:

```
$s = 'http://www.chuckecheese.com/rotator.php?cheese=4&id=1';
$url = parse_url($s);
parse_str($url['query'], $qs);
unset($qs['id']);
$url['query'] = http_build_str($qs);
$out = http_build_url($url);
echo $out;
```

**Note:** this requires the [pecl_http](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.http.php) extension, which you have to compile yourself on Windows it seems.

Answer (score 1):

If the ID really can be anything, try this:

```
$qs = preg_replace("/(&|?)id=[^&]+/", '', $_SERVER[QUERY_STRING]);
```

If the ID is definitely a number, this one should do the trick:

```
$qs = preg_replace("/(&|?)id=\d+/", '', $_SERVER[QUERY_STRING]);
```

Comment: ? is not part of $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] so you should check for something like Beginning, or "&"